# Convert float numbers like 4.8d-1 to 0.48 Linux, SQL?

Tags: mysql, linux

I have a floating point number in file as for example

```
1> 9.0d-1
2> 4.8d-1
```

How to convert these numbers to be represented as normal float numbers. I want to convert in sql or by linux command.

Answer (score 0):

create a Python 2.x script, convert.py, like this:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    n, exp = line.split('d')
    print float(n) * 10 ** int(exp)
```

run it with:

python convert.py < yourfile.txt > newfile.txt